# Live Connect as Azure ACS Identity Provider

Tags: authentication, acs, liveconnect

I am using Azure ACS as a federation gateway for my application and I allow users to authenticate with Google, Yahoo & Windows Live ID.  I need the user's email address. Google and Yahoo provide the email but Windows Live ID does not.

I can get the email address for a user if they authenticate with Live Connect but there is no Live Connect Identity Provider available in Azure ACS.  Is there any way to configure Live Connect as an Identity Provider in ACS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, ACS doesn't currently support Live Connect.

Comment: Thanks.  What are my options then for getting the user's email?

Comment: @user655653 One thing you can do is redirect the user to a registration page after authenticating, asking them to provide an e-mail address, then linking it to the unique identifier provided by Live ID. You can add e-mail validation to make sure the address provided is valid, but there's no way to know if it's actually the same one they used to authenticate.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a way, a bit convoluted, but by becoming the broker and using live connect API, you can achieve this functionality.

Please see: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/Get-Azure-ACS-work-40d588cc#content